# Meaning of "Take something in"

Tags: meaning

> President Trump: We’re looking for a complete deal.  I’m not looking for a partial deal.  China has been starting to buy our agricultural product.  If
>   you noticed over the last week — and actually, some very big
>   purchases.
>
> But that’s not what I’m looking for; we’re looking for the big deal. 
>   We’ve taken it to this level.  **We’re taking in billions and billions of dollars of tariffs.**  China has devalued their currency and they’re
>   putting out a lot of money into their curren- — into their — into
>   their economy.

Hi, I looked for the meaning of take in, and a dictionary says:

> **to accept something as real or true**
>
> He still hasn’t really taken in his father’s death. [Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/take-in#take-in__11)

Is the meaning I found is correct in this case?

And if so, does it mean the U.S. has to accept the billions dollars of tariffs from China?
I know it's related with the economy, but I'd like to know just the meaning of the phrase.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Macmillan provides a UK dictionary defining British English, and "take in" in this context is an American invention, so an American dictionary like Merriam-Webster would provide a more appropriate definition:

> [Take in](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/taking%20in): 3. to receive as payment or proceeds

Comment: Thanks. Then in this context, does it mean the U.S. is receiving billions of dollars of tarrifs from China?

Comment: Yes, that's what the claim is.